# Print code with syntax highlighting on a Mac

Tags: macos, printing, syntax-highlighting

What could I use to print javascript, php or css code in colour? I've tried the following:

1. Textmate
2. Dreamweaver CS3
3. Firefox viewsource extension
4. saving webpage as a pdf

All of these result in black and white code. It seems such a fundamental thing and most Windows text editors have this basic functionality. Has anyone got anything that can do this in OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried TextWrangler or its big brother, BBEdit from Bare Bones Software?

Comment: textwrangler saves the day :) cool little editor.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim/Gvim](http://www.vim.org) has no problem with printing syntax highlighting. Just pick some nice colour scheme (preferably with a white background) and *:hardcopy*.

Comment: i thank you for your help, unfortunately I'm not quite at geek factor 9 yet, so I've chosen a laymans tool :p

Comment: oh, i don't mind ... i also thought gvim was a little weird before i started using it ... then after picking out my brain, and putting it a new one and completely reprogramming it, i now happily use it everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/scripting/index.html) can do this, and it is multiplatform. It can also save the code as a webpage with syntax highlighting that you can print.

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technology/Xcode.html) and [Dashcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/dashcode/) will preserve the syntax highlighting when printing and copying to the clipboard.

Comment: cool i'll check out dashcode, although it appears to have vanished from my os. :)

Comment: @Pickledegg: You'll have to have the Developer Tools installed. They come as an optional install on the Mac OS X installation disc. Alternatively, you can download them from http://developer.apple.com/technology/Xcode.html (free ADC membership required).